# How to access query parameter in serializer django rest framework

Tags: django, django-rest-framework, django-views

I am trying to access query parameter in the serializer. I am not sure what I am doing wrong, I tried to follow a few solution.

```
class MyViewSet(viewsets.ModelViewSet):
    .......
    serializer_class = MySerializer

   def get_serializer_context(self):
      context = super().get_serializer_context()
      context['test'] = "something"
      return context
```

In my Serializer,

```
class MySerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    isHighlight = serializers.SerializerMethodField()

   def get_isHighlight(self, obj):
       print(self.context['test'])
       return self.context['test']
```

I am getting this error,

```
Django Version: 3.2.7
Exception Type: KeyError
Exception Value: 'test'
```

Interestingly, I can see it can print the value in console and then the exception. I also tried to directly access the request variable like

```
class MySerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    isHighlight = serializers.SerializerMethodField()

    def get_isHighlight(self, obj):
        return self.context['request'].query_params['page']
```

But its showing the same error

```
Django Version: 3.2.7
Exception Type: KeyError
Exception Value: 'request'
```

Any suggestions? Thanks in advance.

Comment: What does `self.context` print in the console?

Comment: What does `print(self.context.__dict__.keys())` gives you?

Comment: it crashes and gives this error "'dict' object has no attribute '__dict__'"

Comment: @SihanTawsik I can access the query parameter in get_isHighlight. The problem is that it make the response as 400 at the end. Even if I return a constant like "return 1". Seems like the exception is if I access request parameter in that function.

Comment: `request.query_params.get('yourparamter')`

Comment: @AtifShafi I dont think serializer has the access to request directly.

Comment: I was just wondering what is wrong with this question. Nothing wrong for getting these two negative feedback. but I am just trying to learn what was wrong asking this question.

Answer (score 0):

You can use

```
self.request.query_params.get(<parameter>)
```

also, you can set a default value in case the parameter does not exist

```
self.request.query_params.get(<parameter>, <default>)
```

Another way to do it is using the `GET` attribute of the request

```
self.request.GET.get(<parameter>)
```

I hope it helps you, greetings!